# How to create a new instance of Foo class without exposing its constructor in the interface?

Tags: objective-c, ios

This isn't strictly related to `NewsstandKit.framework`, but there's a live example of this approach in there:

`addIssueWithName:date:` instance method of `NKLibrary` creates a newsstand issue — `NKIssue` — and adds it to the content library and in case of non–failure returns it. At this point `NKIssue` instance has `name` and `date` properties are set to values passed to `addIssueWithName:date:` initially.

If you check that out, `NKIssue` class doesn't have a specific initialization method (other than plain `init` inherited from `NSObject`) nor `@public` instance variables (e.g. `_name` and `_date`) and its properties are all `readonly`.

So I don't get how this whole thing could work internally? I would love to mimic this approach in one of my libraries, but can't really figure out how...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's code has access to Apple's code. The `readonly` properties of `NKIssue` are likely re-declared as `readwrite` in a class extension. Have a look at ["Property Redeclaration"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW19) in TOCPL.

In the header, you see:

```
@interface Carborundum : NSObject
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString * whiskers;
@property (readonly, retain, nonatomic) NSDate * inception;
@end
```

In the implementation file (or other private file) there's a class extension that has the same properties, with the exact same attributes (this is required) except `readonly`.

```
@interface Carborundum ()
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString * whiskers;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDate * inception;
@end
```

They're synthesized as usual:

```
@implementation Carborundum

@synthesize whiskers;
@synthesize inception;

@end
```

This allows code that can see the class extension (i.e., other UIKit code) to use the properties as read-write, while your code, which only has access to the header, is limited to the read-only version. This is enforced by the compiler, not the runtime.

There's a fair number of SO questions that go into this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+redeclare+property

Comment: How would you `@synthesize` those in implementation please?